# How to implement logic on stop and start of Java windows service wrapper YAJSW?

Tags: java, windows, service

I'm leatning to work with YAJSW for wrapping java apps into windows services. It works fine with starting application but I want to know how to implement logic in the java application so that when I stop a service it would perform that logic inside the java application.

Something like implementing onStart() and onStop() methods in my java application so I can call these when I start or stop a java service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call your onStart() method/logic right inside your main method which is the entry point for your application. In order to implement onStop(), this is how we have done it ...

step-1) Create following class ...

```
public class ShutdownHandler implements Runnable {
    public ShutdownHandler() {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // call to your onStop() or code right here;
    }
}
```

step-2) Inside the main method ...

```
Thread shutdownThread = new Thread(new ShutdownHandler());
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(shutdownThread);
```

This will invoke the ShutdownHandler's run method when your java application terminates. Hope this helps.